# GitLab CD/CD: is there a way to allow to force execute pipeline stage B manually if previous stage A failed, else execute stage B automatically?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

Consider GitLab CI/CD pipeline consisting of two consequent stages: A and B.

If stage A succeeds, I want stage B to be executed automatically.
But if stage A fails, I don't want stage B to be executed automatically, but still have a possibility to force execute stage B manually.

How can I achive that?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways I can see to achieve that (when your pipeline fails you will need to manually trigger whole pipeline again, not just one stage):

1. Mark job in stage B [when: always](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when) to execute job regardless of the status of jobs from prior stages.

```yaml
firstFailingJob:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo I will always fail
    - exit 1

secondExecuteWhenManualTrigger:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo I should run even when first failed when triggered manually
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
      when: always
    - when: on_success
```

Note that the result of whole pipeline will be **failed**, as ilustrated below.
[image: Always execute second job for manual trigger]
 2. Mark possibly failing job with [allow_failure: true](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure) to fail without impacting the rest of the CI suite.

```yaml
firstFailingJob:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo I will always fail
    - exit 1
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
      allow_failure: true
    - allow_failure: false
...
```

Result of whole pipeline will be **passed with warnings** as ilustrated below.
[image: Allow failure]

`$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"` means pipeline has been triggered from GitLab gui `Project page -> CI/CD -> Run Pipeline`. You can always setup different conditions with any variable custom or [predefined](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#variables-reference).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with stages.

> Jobs of the next stage are run after the jobs from the previous stage
>   complete successfully.

That's per https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages

There is no way to make a stage be manually triggered.